# How to use EventBus in Activity and Fragment on Android

Tags: java, android, event-bus

In my application i want use **EventBus** for call some methods in another **activities**. 
I want when click on `backButton` in `activity` (**DetailActivity**), call one method in `fragment` (**MainFragment**).
in **MainFragment** i have `recyclerView` and open this `activity` (**DetailActivity**) with `recyclerView adapter`.

I write below codes in **DetailActivity** and **MainFragment** but when click on `backButton`, **not call method** in **MainFragment**.

**MainFragment codes :**

```
public void onStart() {
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}

@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onRefreshAuctions(EventUpdateAuctionsState event){
    Toast.makeText(context, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**DetailActivity codes :**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finishWithAnimate();
    EventBus.getDefault().post(new EventUpdateAuctionsState());
}
```

**EventUpdateAuctionsState codes :**

```
public class EventUpdateAuctionsState {
    public EventUpdateAuctionsState() {
    }
}
```

Why not call method in MainFragment? 
How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your Fragment is in stopped state when event is fired. Try to register, unregister in create/destroy lifecycle.

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}
```

**Suggestion**

By the way why are you using EventBus for just backpress implementation. You can simply do this. If you fragment is child of `DetailActivity`.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finishWithAnimate();
    // get your fragment
    if(fragment!=null) fragment.onRefreshAuctions();
}
```

You can use `getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tag")` if you don't have fragment instance.

Comment: i don't know your part two. can you send to me codes with my above codes? please bro. i really need your help

Comment: `MainFragment` is started from `DetailActivity`?

Comment: No my bro, In my **MainActivity** i have 4 tab and **MainFragment** has one of this 4 tabs. in this **MainFragment** i have **recyclerView** for show some list from server, when user click on one of this **adapter's** items show **DetailActivity** with below code : `Intent intent = new Intent(context, RegisterInAuctionActivity.class);    Intent intent = new Intent(context, RegisterInAuctionActivity.class);`

Comment: Try `EventBus.getDefault().post...` in `onDestroy` of `DetailActivity`.

Comment: Thanks when write into onDestroy call method. but why not call when use in OnBackPress ?

Comment: I think your Event is not fired because you already call `finishWithAnimate`.